# Looping through Textboxes to retrieve data, c#

Tags: c#, textbox, foreach

I have a class called "Player" with a constructor that takes 2 strings and an int.

These are declared in Textboxes on a form, with each team (Home H / Away A) having a different name, and each name type (Last L / First F) adding to the textbox's name. therefor giving a unique name such as `txtFHome1`.

In a `foreach` loop I want to create a new Player with the details of the textboxes on a page.

This is what I have got so far.

```
List <Player> HomeTeam = new List<Player>    

private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
     {
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          {
            HomeTeam.Add (new Player(c.Name.EndsWith("FHome"+i),c.Name.EndsWith("LHome"+i),c.Name.EndsWith("upDownH"+i)));
          }
     }
}
```

any help?

Comment: You have to add more details of the players class.

Answer (score 1):

From you post I understand that there are always 3 controls for 11 players, so there is no need to iterate trough all `Controls` in the form.

```
private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
          var player = new Player(((TextBox)this.Controls.FindControl("FHome" + i)).Text, ((TextBox)this.Controls.FindControl("LHome" + i)).Text, ((NumericUpDown)this.Controls.FindControl("upDownH" + i)).Value);
          HomeTeam.Add(player);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first way is to use dictionaries with all controls. It is the fastest and easiest way.

```
Dictionary<int, TextBox> FHome;
Dictionary<int, TextBox> LHome;
Dictionary<int, TextBox> upDownH;
```

You should add the controls like this:

```
FHome.Add(0, textBoxLHome0);
FHome.Add(1, textBoxLHome1);
```

Then in your code you can use

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    HomeTeam.Add (new Player(FHome[i].Text, LHome[i].Text, upDownH[i].Text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach((textbox) =>
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        textbox.Text = "your text";
      }
    });
```

remember to include `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to at lease try an encapsulate the three textboxes into a single UserControl like so:

[image]

```
public partial class ControlPlayerParams : UserControl {

    public string Param1 { get { return this.textBox1.Text; } }
    public string Param2 { get { return this.textBox2.Text; } }
    public string Param3 { get { return this.textBox3.Text; } }

    public ControlPlayerParams() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

That way, you could at least do what you wanted to do more fluently and more safely (plus you get to modify just one UserControl in case you need something changed (Validation ??)):

```
foreach (ControlPlayerParams cpp in this.Controls.OfType<ControlPlayerParams>())
  HomeTeam.Add(new Player(cpp.Param1, cpp.Param2, cpp.Param3));
```

**BUT** you should rethink the architecture of the app a bit if you ask me.